# Macbook External Display Goes Black After 10 seconds when using an HDMI Splitter

Tags: display, hdmi

I am using a MacBook Pro 13" M1 2020, running Big Sur 11.5.1. I am trying to connect an external display with a USB C -> HDMI cable. When connected directly everything works perfectly, however when I use an HDMI splitter, the external display comes on for only 10 seconds then goes black. However the display continues to be detected and shows in the settings. Some further information

- This HDMI splitter works perfectly with my Ubuntu and Windows PC. It also works properly when using a display link USD to HDMI adapter from my macbook. Only causes issues with a USB C to HDMI converter.
- I have tried plugging in the USB-C to HDMI setup (with the splitter) to 2 samsung phones, and each one works perfectly + is capable of outputting a display (this is basically the same exact setup, but replacing a macbook with a phone)
- I have tried multiple different USB-C to HDMI converters and different HDMI cables, they all have the same issue.
- I have tried lowering the resolution/display/etc and have had no luck.

Comment: Make and model of the splitter and other converters would help. They're not all created equal, and some are quite shoddily constructed and/or not up to spec.

Comment: This is the switch: https://www.amazon.ca/HDMI-FiveHome-Switcher-Wireless-Support/dp/B076XWNQP9